# OCaml regex being buggy when trying to use escape characters

Tags: regex, ocaml

I'm trying to write a lexer for a variation on C using OCaml. For the lexer I need to match the strings "^" and "||" (as the exponentiation and or symbols respectively). Both of these are special characters in regex, and when I try to escape them using the backslash, nothing changes and the code runs as if "\^" was still beginning of line and "\|\|" was still "or or". What can I do to fix this?

Comment: Try enclosing with `[...]`: `[^]` and `[|]`.

Comment: Are you using ocamllex? Or something else?

Answer (score 7):

Backslash characters in string literals have to be doubled to make them past the OCaml string parser:

```
# let r = Str.regexp "\\^" in
    Str.search_forward r "FOO^BAR" 0;;
- : int = 3
```

If you are using OCaml 4.02 or later, you can also use [quoted strings (`{| ... |}`)](https://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml-4.06/extn.html#sec263), which do not handle a backslash character specially. This may result in more readable code because backslash characters do not have to be doubled:

```
# let r = Str.regexp {|\^|} in
    Str.search_forward r "FOO^BAR" 0;;
- : int = 3
```

Or you may consider using [`Str.regexp_string`](https://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/Str.html#VALregexp_string) (or [`Str.quote`](https://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/Str.html#VALquote)), which creates a regular expression that will match all characters in its argument literally:

```
# let r = Str.regexp_string "^" in
    Str.search_forward r "FOO^BAR" 0;;
- : int = 3
```

---

The `Str` module does not take `|` as a special regex character, so you do not have to worry about quoting when you want to use it literally:

```
# let r = Str.regexp "||" in
    Str.search_forward r "FOO||BAR" 0;;
- : int = 3
```

`|` has to be quoted only when you want to use it as the "or" construct:

```
# let r = Str.regexp "BAZ\\|BAR" in
    Str.search_forward r "FOOBAR" 0;;
- : int = 3
```

---

You might want to refer to [Str.regexp](https://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/Str.html#VALregexp) for the full syntax of regular expressions.