# How to delete all char of a string in OCaml

Tags: string, replace, char, ocaml

Is there an easy way to delete all occurrences of a char in an OCaml string ?

I thought I could use this clean function :

```ml
let clean = 
  function 
  | ' ' | '[' | ']' | '\n' | '>' -> '' 
  | x -> x 
in
```

But you can't use `''` in OCaml.

So I came with this solution :

```ml
let delete = 
  function 
    | ' ' | '[' | ']' | '\n' | '>' -> true 
    | _ -> false 
  in 
  let char_list, size =
    String.fold_left 
      (fun (acc, count) c -> 
        if delete c then acc, count 
        else c::acc, count+1) ([],0) path_string 
  in
  let char_list = ref @@ List.rev char_list in 
  let aux() = 
    match !char_list with 
    | [] -> failwith "unexpected"
    | x :: xs -> char_list := xs; x
  in
  let cleaned_string = String.init size (fun _ -> aux()) in 
  cleaned_string
```

But it's big - with python it's just `s.replace('>','')` to suppress one - and only work with `OCaml 4.13` which is not supported for my installation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The closest equivalent to python might be [`Str.global_replace`](https://ocaml.org/api/Str.html#VALglobal_replace):

```
Str.(global_replace (regexp ">") "" s)
```

or to do multiple characters at once you could do something like:

```
Str.(global_replace (regexp "[youChar1yourChar2yourChar3]") "" s)
```

So in your case :

```
Str.(global_replace (regexp "[][> \n]") "" s)
```

Comment: seems like now you only need one `"\"` before the brackets for the regex expression to work in this online compiler :  https://regex101.com/. For now the program above doesn't work on my side : https://pastebin.com/90EwX5Qq. And if I try this string `"[ >\[\]\n]"` OCaml throws an error

Comment: It seems that the the Str regexp can't handle the `]` @glennsl

Comment: I read [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43307623/ocaml-regex-being-buggy-when-trying-to-use-escape-characters) and replacing the current regexp by `regexp {|[][> \n]|}` does the job

Comment: That's very weird. I don't see how it's able to delimit the character class without escaping the delimiters. Another alternative would be to use alternation (`\|`), but I think your solution is better. I'll update my answer to use that instead.

Comment: actually my solution doesn't delete but  "[][> \n]" works x)

Answer (score 4):

If you want to build a string dynamically, you should use a buffer

```ml
let remove_chars erase s =
  let b = Buffer.create 10 in
  String.iter (fun c -> if not (erase c) then Buffer.add_char b c);
  Buffer.contents b
```

(Building a list of characters is extremely inefficient.)